# How to disable momentary highlighting of a match by xref and ggtags?

Tags: highlighting, xref, ggtags

When I call `gtags-find-tag-dwim`, matches item will be highlighted for about one second.

When I call `xref-pop-marker-stack`, matches item will be highlighted for about 0.2 second.

like this:
[image]

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
Add after Drew reply:

There will be an annoying underline when `ggtags-highlight-tag` is the default value. Setting this variable to `nil` can prevent this underline, but the highlighting problem still exists, The default effect is as follows:

[image]

--------------------------------------------
**NOTE:**
I'm having trouble and I can't find any results using customize:
[image]
customize-apropos: No customizable group, face, or option matching (ggtags)

Answer (score 1):

A good approach for finding such info is to look for hooks and user options.  I found these answers just by looking in the relevant source files.

---

For Xref:

```lisp
(remove-hook 'xref-after-return-hook 'xref-pulse-momentarily)
```

Or `M-x customize-option xref-after-return-hook` and remove hook function `xref-pulse-momentarily`.

---

For `ggtags`:

Customize option `ggtags-highlight-tag` to disable that highlighting.

**NOTE:** Don't just use `setq` to set the option to `nil`.  Use the Customize UI.  This is because the `defcustom` has a `:set` function that needs to be invoked.

Comment: Hi, `xref-after-return-hook` this worked for me.
I know to set `ggtags-highlight-tag` to `nil`, but this just prevents the underline from being displayed, the highlight problem still exists.

Comment: Please describe "the highlight problem" better, then. In any case, the code in `ggtags.el` is your friend - it's likely that it's there that "the highlight problem" is being done.

Comment: See the NOTE I added to the answer.

Comment: I added my question, I cannot use Customize UI, it’s like a bug

Comment: `M-x customize-option RET ggtags-highlight-tag RET`

Comment: I after I enable `ggtags-mode`, I can use `customize-option`, but it still highlights. I think `ggtags-highlight-tag` just solves the underscore problem.