# How to disable momentary highlighting of a match by ggtags?

Tags: highlighting, ggtags

When I call gtags-find-tag-dwim, matches item will be highlighted for about one second.
Like this:
[image]

Please note that `ggtags-highlight-tag` has absolutely nothing to do with this highlight, I believe this is caused by another mysterious problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable momentary highlighting of a match by xref and ggtags?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69589/how-to-disable-momentary-highlighting-of-a-match-by-xref-and-ggtags)

Comment: @db48x The `xref-pop-marker-stack` problem is solved, but the highlighting problem of `gtags-find-tag-dwim` still exists

Comment: Answers to that part should be posted to the original question. But in the future you should pose only one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggtags-find-tag-dwim` relies on `compilation-mode` to jump to the determined location.  The variable that controls how (and if) `compilation-mode` highlights locations is `next-error-highlight`.  Setting it to `nil` will disable the highlighting.

Comment: Please consider posting this answer to the original question, of which this is a duplicate.